# Magnitude and phase of complex number with increasing exponential

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to form the magnitude and phase of the following complex number:

$$[1 + exp(i\theta) + exp(i2\theta) + exp(i3\theta) + exp(i4\theta)]$$

I was told to take the $exp(i2\theta)$ outside and simplify using Euler's formula, but I've reached a block.

$$\Rightarrow exp(i2\theta)[exp(-i2\theta) + exp(-i\theta) + 1 + exp(i\theta) + exp(i2\theta)]$$
$$\Rightarrow exp(i2\theta)[cos(2\theta) - isin(2\theta) + cos(\theta) - isin(\theta) + 1 + cos(\theta) + isin(\theta) + cos(2\theta) + isin(2\theta)]$$
$$\Rightarrow exp(i2\theta)[2cos(2\theta) + 2cos(\theta) + 1]$$
Now I'm not sure where to go, when I try expanding anything it seems to become more complicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Notice you are dealing with a geometric progression whose common ratio equals $e^{i\theta}$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{ik\theta} = \frac{1 - e^{in\theta}}{1 - e^{i\theta}}
\end{align*}

Make $n = 5$ and simplify the resulting expression.